# How to show a plot created by plt.plot()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using the following piece of code

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [2, 6, 5, 12, 10, 16]

data_viz = plt.plot(x, y)

.... other code 

plt.show(data_viz)
```

When I run this, I dont get any results. Its simply a blank - no error, nothing. I wish to display the plot which I saved as data_viz. What can I do?

I am using Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter lab or Google colab but both are getting the same issue.

I tested this code on Chatgpt and it doesnt find any error. I tried googling it but havent been able to find a relevant answer.

Comment: *"I tested this code on Chatgpt"* -> please don't mention ChatGPT here, it's irrelevant… *"I tried googling"* without specifics it also not helpful. Have you tried to run the code without `%matplotlib inline` nor `plot.show()`. Jupyter shouldn't need those.

Answer (score 0):

You do not show a variable in `matplotlib` with `plt.show`. Just call `plt.show()` after you have set up all the plots and settings with `matplotlib` and it will show the graph.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [2, 6, 5, 12, 10, 16]

data_viz = plt.plot(x, y)

# .... other code

plt.show()
```

The variable `data_viz` (a `<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object`) is probably not really necessary, just `plt.plot(x, y)` will do.

I suggest to explore some [matplotlib examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index) and some [documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-matplotlib-with-jupyter-notebook/) on how to use `matplotlib` in `Jupyter notebook', which basically gives you the answer. Googling is a real help and indispensable when stuck in coding :).